# IBM worklight 6.0 - Class org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver not found in Worklight platform or project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

When i'm using worklight 5.0.6 every thing run ok,but when i upgrade worklight to 6.0.0, i've got that error when running  my adapters.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok ,i've answer just download derbyclient-10.8.2.2.jar then copy to server/lib then every thing ok.